# Referencing StreamReader in two methods

Tags: c#, streamreader

Quite new to OO so please be kind.

I have created a method which when button1 is clicked, opens a file dialog and reads the contents into a stream reader sr;

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(label1.Text);
            String strNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
            label2.Text = strNumVertices;
        }
    }
```

The other code runs in the Form1_Paint method.

```
public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

        perspectiveMatrix = new Gmatrix("perspective");
        translationMatrix = new Gmatrix("translation");
        scalingMatrix = new Gmatrix("scaling");

        perspectiveMatrix.initAsPerspectiveMatrix(300);

        scalingMatrix.initAsScalingMatrix(10, 10, 10);

        translationMatrix.initAsTranslationMatrix(150, 50, 1200);

       String strNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
        label1.Text = strNumVertices;
```

My question is, How do I reference stream reader sr from the button1_click method in the Form1_paint method?

Answer (score 4):

Word of advice - don't try.

If you do so, you are in danger of having open files/streams all over the place.

I suggest you open a new steam reader in each method (or abstract it away into its own method).

Note:

You should be wrapping the opening of the stream in a `using` statement, to ensure proper disposal:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(label1.Text))
{
   String strNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
   label2.Text = strNumVertices;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should be not the best idea to read from the stream during each paint run. Perhaps you'd like to read the value once, store it in the member variable of your form, and access in the paint method?

Comment: haha, you beat me to the punch cos my boss came over for a chat. You've got enough rep, go on, delete your answer and let me have the qudos. ;)

Comment: @BenCr: I've upvoted yours instead, anyway we both write basically the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you expect the file to have changed between the button click and the paint method being called then you shouldn't be reading from the file again anyway.

Reading the file is very expensive in terms of performance compared to storing the result in a field and retreiving it during the paint method. Or visa versa depending what executes first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the data you've read from the file and re-use it rather than reading the file again?  I'm assuming these methods are in the same class (and the same instance of the object), but there are ways around that if that's not true.

```
private string StrNumVertices { get; set; }


public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(label1.Text);
        this.StrNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
        label2.Text = this.StrNumVertices;
    }
}

public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

    perspectiveMatrix = new Gmatrix("perspective");
    translationMatrix = new Gmatrix("translation");
    scalingMatrix = new Gmatrix("scaling");

    perspectiveMatrix.initAsPerspectiveMatrix(300);

    scalingMatrix.initAsScalingMatrix(10, 10, 10);

    translationMatrix.initAsTranslationMatrix(150, 50, 1200);

    label1.Text = this.StrNumVertices;

    ...
}
```

If it's not the same instance of the object, then I'd consider using a Singleton configuration object (or cache) and storing the data there.  It really depends, of course, on the scope and lifetime of the data -- does it apply to the whole application or just this instance?  The best way, of course, is to make it an instance property like above, and I assume this will work, but if you're recreating the object you will have to use a different technique.

If you really do want to read the file again (because the data is from a different line), you will need to re-use the stream or, again, read all of the data in one go -- if possible -- then iterate through the items you've read internally.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a field on the form class. This changes the scope from the method to the entire form. The warnings from the previous post are still valid.

```
StreamReader sr;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        sr = new StreamReader(label1.Text);
        String strNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
        label2.Text = strNumVertices;
    }
}

public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

    perspectiveMatrix = new Gmatrix("perspective");
    translationMatrix = new Gmatrix("translation");
    scalingMatrix = new Gmatrix("scaling");

    perspectiveMatrix.initAsPerspectiveMatrix(300);

    scalingMatrix.initAsScalingMatrix(10, 10, 10);

    translationMatrix.initAsTranslationMatrix(150, 50, 1200);

    if (sr != null) {
       String strNumVertices = sr.ReadLine();
       label1.Text = strNumVertices;
    }
```

Comment: Although this does answer the question, i would question this approach - 1.Leaving an open stream 2.ReadLine() in every paint is going to be very slow 3.When the file gets to the end it will blow up

Comment: The code you suggested, whilst it represents the solution I was looking for, it does not populate label1 with the value of strNumVertices in the Form1_Paint method, why is this please?

Comment: Richards' comment is quite right, this leaves the stream open. The problem this leaves is that when you reach the end of the stream, sr.ReadLine() will return null, meaning it'll set the label to null. tvanfosson's solution is probably more what you actually want, but this should still be helpful to learning OO :) If you still want to read the while stream each time, sr.BaseStream.Position = 0 will reset the read position in the stream.